# Most efficient way to update NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I was asked in an interview today to tell about the most efficient way to update an NSMutableArray. My answer to that was to use `-insertObject:atIndex` method call. But I was told by the interviewer that there is more efficient way present.

In Objective-C, as far as I know, the wrappers like NSMutableArray does all the heavy lifting and we as developer, don't have to worry about the data structure implementation. How true is this? What is the better way of updating the NSMutableArray. Probably create my own implementation say SOMutableArray?

Comment: Not sure what he meant either. Neither did he define what he meant by "efficient" so one could only guess what criteria one should base the requirements/considerations upon. This is a very bad interview question, and the behavior of the interviewer guy is even worse.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: This was exactly what I was asked, and told. I assumed the time-wise efficiency here.

Comment: Maybe the interviewer wanted to know if you would be honest enough to admit not to know something? while there are some articles about array behaviour observations out there, in the end it is an implementation detail apple doesn't share with us.

Comment: http://ciechanowski.me/blog/2014/03/05/exposing-nsmutablearray/ This article suggests that adding at the end and adding at the beginning would be equally efficient. if that is what was meant with updating.

Comment: I'm with viking. NSMutableArray is part of a class cluster, and insertObject:atIndex: is one of the primitive methods that the class is built from. The internals of Apple's implementation are private, so I'm not sure what safe way you could use, unless he meant to use replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:, which would change the array without having to resize it, and most likely be faster than inserting an object, but it doesn't do the same thing.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to programmers.stackexchange.com, not SO.

Comment: @rmaddy: funnily this depends: if there is a valid answer, it would belong here. if not the thoughts about the question might fit better to programmers.SE

Comment: @vikingosegundo I saw a good summary (I'm sure there are exceptions): If the question doesn't have code and it's more of a mental exercise, use programmers. If you have working code that needs improving, use codereview. If you have broken code, use SO.

Comment: The interviewer's question doesn't even make sense. Unless he or she says what they mean by "updating", it is impossible to answer the question.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: To be more precise, inserting or removing an element k positions from either the start or the end of the array takes O (k) with a very small constant. BTW this isn't true for Swift arrays where inserting/deleting at the start if the array is slow.